# ag grid conditionally use cellRendererFramework

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

Is it possible to based on condition choose one of the cellRendererFramework like this:

```
{
    headerName: 'Name header',
    field: 'field',
    editable: true,
    cellRendererSelector: function (params) {
        let oneOfRenderFramework = {};
        if (params.data.someId === '12345') {
            oneOfRenderFramework = {
                cellRendererFramework: OneCellRendererFramework,
            };
        } else {
            oneOfRenderFramework = {
                cellRendererFramework: TwoCellRendererFramework,
            };
        }

        return oneOfRenderFramework;
    },
},
```

Comment: It should be, yes. Have you tried?